# git not overwriting remote repo with local files?

Tags: git, github

I am very new to git and I have the following issue (I am trying to overwrite local files to remote repo).
say I have files in `\project`that I want to push to my remote github repo and overwrite some of files.
I did some search and in the `\project` directory I did the following:

```
git add .
```

and then

```
git push -u origin master
```

and I also tried `git push -f origin master` and the git always returns a message saying *everything up-to-date*, but I clearly have different files locally and when I tried to refresh my github repo, no change has been made..

Comment: You forgot `git commit`; run `git status`, you'll see there's files staged for commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

updating remote repository is done with following steps:

to add changed files for commit:

```
git add -A
```

to make a commit locally:

```
git commit -m "test commit"
```

to push locally made commit to remote

```
git push
```